# How to remove duplicates from csv file in java

Tags: java, csv, duplicates

I am trying to remove content that have duplicates of tweet token (column[5]) from the csv file that was created by `eventDetectionName()`, but after running `EventDetectioncopy.java`, duplicates of tweet token was removed but some duplicates still exist.

Duplicate of tweet token means that the string of tweet token have the same content in the same cluster id.

Here is the code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class EventDetectioncopy {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        System.out.print("Enter a name for new Tweet Cluster sorting by name entity: ");
        BufferedReader scanName = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String newNamefile = scanName.readLine();

        System.out.print("Enter a name for new Tweet Cluster sorting by tweet tokens: ");
        BufferedReader scanToken = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String newTokenfile = scanToken.readLine();
        try{

            eventDetectionName(newNamefile);
            eventDetectionToken(newNamefile, newTokenfile);

        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        catch (IOException e){}
    }

    //remove duplicate tweet token
    public static void eventDetectionToken(String fileInput, String fileOutput) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        FileWriter newCsv = new FileWriter(fileOutput + ".csv");
        BufferedWriter newCsvBW = new BufferedWriter(newCsv);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileInput + ".csv"));
        String data;
        try{
            String temp = null;
            List<String> tempList = new ArrayList<String>();
            do
            {
                data = reader.readLine();
                String tweetToken = null;

                if(data != null)
                {
                    String[] splitText = data.split(",");
                    tweetToken = splitText[5];
                }

                if(temp != null)
                {
                    if (data == null || tweetToken.contains(tweetToken))
                    {
                        if (!(temp.equals(tweetToken)))
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < tempList.size(); i++) 
                            {
                                newCsvBW.append(tempList.get(i));
                                newCsvBW.append("\n");
                            }
                        }
                        tempList.clear();
                        temp = tweetToken;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    temp = tweetToken;
                }
                tempList.add(data);
            }
            while(data != null);
        }
        finally
        {
            newCsvBW.close();
            reader.close();
        }
    }

    //entity name that occurs more than 10 times
    public static void eventDetectionName(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        String csv = "1day/clusters.sortedby.clusterid.csv";
        FileWriter newCsv = new FileWriter(filename + ".csv");
        BufferedWriter newCsvBW = new BufferedWriter(newCsv);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csv));
        String data;

        try{
            String temp = null;
            List<String> tempList = new ArrayList<String>();
            do 
            {
                data = reader.readLine();
                String nameEntity = null;
                if (data != null) 
                {
                    String[] splitText = data.split(",");
                    nameEntity = splitText[1];
                }
                if (temp != null) 
                {
                    if (data == null || !(nameEntity.equals(temp))) 
                    {
                        if (tempList.size() >= 10) 
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < tempList.size(); i++) 
                            {
                                newCsvBW.append(tempList.get(i));
                                newCsvBW.append("\n");
                            }
                        }
                        tempList.clear();
                        temp = nameEntity;
                    }
                } 
                else 
                {
                    temp = nameEntity;
                }
                tempList.add(data);
            } 
            while (data != null);
        }
        finally
        {
            reader.close();
            newCsvBW.close();
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the original content with duplicates after performing `eventDetectionName()` to sort entity name that occurs more than 10 times, where duplicates are not taken care of yet:

```
[clusterid], [name entitiy], [tweetid], [timestamp], [userid], [tweet token], [tweet text]

    7722    lenovo  2.56142E+17 1.3499E+12  236705687   lenovo top hp becom 1 pc maker zdnet lenovo top hp becom 1 pc makerzdnetsummari china le    Lenovo tops HP to become No. 1 PC maker - ZDNet: Lenovo tops HP to become No. 1 PC makerZDNetSummary: China's Le... 
    7722    lenovo  2.56143E+17 1.3499E+12  72541972    lenovo top hp becom 1 pc maker zdnet lenovo top hp becom 1 pc makerzdnetsummari china le    Lenovo tops HP to become No. 1 PC maker - ZDNet: Lenovo tops HP to become No. 1 PC makerZDNetSummary: China's Le...
    7722    lenovo  2.56165E+17 1.34991E+12 112115244   lenovo overtak hp world top pc maker q3 Lenovo Overtakes HP as Worldâ€™s Top PC Maker in Q3 
    7722    lenovo  2.56165E+17 1.34991E+12 14886375    ahess247 lenovo overtak hp world top pc maker one market survey hpq dell aapl   RT @ahess247 Lenovo Overtakes HP as World's Top PC Maker In One Market Survey $HPQ $DELL $AAPL
    7722    lenovo  2.56167E+17 1.34991E+12 43468679    cna lenovo top hp world biggest pc maker new york chines manufactur lenovo overtaken us base    CNA - Lenovo tops HP as world's biggest PC maker: NEW YORK: Chinese manufacturer Lenovo has overtaken US-based H... 
    7722    lenovo  2.56167E+17 1.34991E+12 231001548   lenovo top hp world biggest pc maker new york chines manufactur lenovo overtaken us base hewlett    Lenovo tops HP as world's biggest PC maker: NEW YORK: Chinese manufacturer Lenovo has overtaken US-based Hewlett... 
    7722    lenovo  2.5617E+17  1.34991E+12 309407203   hp lenovo battl top spot pc market computerworld    HP, Lenovo battle for top spot in PC market - Computerworld 
    7722    lenovo  2.5617E+17  1.34991E+12 865570603   hp lenovo battl top spot pc market computerworld    HP, Lenovo battle for top spot in PC market - Computerworld 
    7722    lenovo  2.5617E+17  1.34991E+12 865474436   hp lenovo battl top spot pc market computerworld    HP, Lenovo battle for top spot in PC market - Computerworld 
    7722    lenovo  2.5617E+17  1.34991E+12 19961203    reddingnewsblog hp lenovo battl top spot pc market computerworld afphp lenovo battl top spot    ReddingNewsBlog HP, Lenovo battle for top spot in PC market - Computerworld: AFPHP, Lenovo battle for top spot i... 
    7722    lenovo  2.56171E+17 1.34991E+12 131477801   hp lenovo battl top spot pc market computerworld    HP, Lenovo battle for top spot in PC market - Computerworld
    7722    lenovo  2.56171E+17 1.34991E+12 138389154   hp lenovo battl top spot pc market computerworld    HP, Lenovo battle for top spot in PC market - Computerworld
    7722    lenovo  2.56171E+17 1.34991E+12 297753408   hp lenovo battl top spot pc market computerworld afphp lenovo battl top spot pc marketcompu HP, Lenovo battle for top spot in PC market - Computerworld: AFPHP, Lenovo battle for top spot in PC marketCompu... 
    7722    lenovo  2.56174E+17 1.34991E+12 558600336   hp lenovo battl top spot pc market computerworld    HP, Lenovo battle for top spot in PC market - Computerworld 
    7722    lenovo  2.56174E+17 1.34991E+12 367209383   hp lenovo battl top spot pc market computerworld    HP, Lenovo battle for top spot in PC market - Computerworld 
    7722    lenovo  2.56174E+17 1.34991E+12 755374159   hp lenovo battl top spot pc market computerworld    HP, Lenovo battle for top spot in PC market - Computerworld 
    7722    lenovo  2.56174E+17 1.34991E+12 36024932    hp lenovo battl top spot pc market computerworld wall street journalhp lenovo battl top spot    HP, Lenovo battle for top spot in PC market - Computerworld: Wall Street JournalHP, Lenovo battle for top spot i... 
    7722    lenovo  2.56176E+17 1.34991E+12 18437660    lenovo pass hp top pc maker ft  Lenovo passes HP to be top PC maker: #FT
    7722    lenovo  2.56176E+17 1.34991E+12 543944864   hp lenovo battl top spot pc market computerworld googlenew  HP, Lenovo battle for top spot in PC market - Computerworld #googlenews
    7722    lenovo  2.56179E+17 1.34991E+12 113671593   lenovo pass hp top pc maker Lenovo passes HP to be top PC maker
```

Here is the output after performing `eventDetectionToken()` where it is supposed to remove duplicates but only some duplicates were removed:

```
[clusterid], [name entitiy], [tweetid], [timestamp], [userid], [tweet token], [tweet text]

    7722    lenovo  2.56143E+17 1.3499E+12  72541972    lenovo top hp becom 1 pc maker zdnet lenovo top hp becom 1 pc makerzdnetsummari china le    Lenovo tops HP to become No. 1 PC maker - ZDNet: Lenovo tops HP to become No. 1 PC makerZDNetSummary: China's Le...
    7722    lenovo  2.56165E+17 1.34991E+12 112115244   lenovo overtak hp world top pc maker q3 Lenovo Overtakes HP as Worldâ€™s Top PC Maker in Q3
    7722    lenovo  2.56165E+17 1.34991E+12 14886375    ahess247 lenovo overtak hp world top pc maker one market survey hpq dell aapl   RT @ahess247 Lenovo Overtakes HP as World's Top PC Maker In One Market Survey $HPQ $DELL $AAPL
    7722    lenovo  2.56167E+17 1.34991E+12 43468679    cna lenovo top hp world biggest pc maker new york chines manufactur lenovo overtaken us base    CNA - Lenovo tops HP as world's biggest PC maker: NEW YORK: Chinese manufacturer Lenovo has overtaken US-based H...
    7722    lenovo  2.56167E+17 1.34991E+12 231001548   lenovo top hp world biggest pc maker new york chines manufactur lenovo overtaken us base hewlett    Lenovo tops HP as world's biggest PC maker: NEW YORK: Chinese manufacturer Lenovo has overtaken US-based Hewlett...
    7722    lenovo  2.5617E+17  1.34991E+12 865474436   hp lenovo battl top spot pc market computerworld    HP, Lenovo battle for top spot in PC market - Computerworld 
    7722    lenovo  2.5617E+17  1.34991E+12 19961203    reddingnewsblog hp lenovo battl top spot pc market computerworld afphp lenovo battl top spot    ReddingNewsBlog HP, Lenovo battle for top spot in PC market - Computerworld: AFPHP, Lenovo battle for top spot i... 
    7722    lenovo  2.56171E+17 1.34991E+12 138389154   hp lenovo battl top spot pc market computerworld    HP, Lenovo battle for top spot in PC market - Computerworld 
    7722    lenovo  2.56171E+17 1.34991E+12 297753408   hp lenovo battl top spot pc market computerworld afphp lenovo battl top spot pc marketcompu HP, Lenovo battle for top spot in PC market - Computerworld: AFPHP, Lenovo battle for top spot in PC marketCompu... 
    7722    lenovo  2.56174E+17 1.34991E+12 755374159   hp lenovo battl top spot pc market computerworld    HP, Lenovo battle for top spot in PC market - Computerworld 
    7722    lenovo  2.56174E+17 1.34991E+12 36024932    hp lenovo battl top spot pc market computerworld wall street journalhp lenovo battl top spot    HP, Lenovo battle for top spot in PC market - Computerworld: Wall Street JournalHP, Lenovo battle for top spot i... 
    7722    lenovo  2.56176E+17 1.34991E+12 18437660    lenovo pass hp top pc maker ft  Lenovo passes HP to be top PC maker: #FT
    7722    lenovo  2.56176E+17 1.34991E+12 543944864   hp lenovo battl top spot pc market computerworld googlenew  HP, Lenovo battle for top spot in PC market - Computerworld #googlenews
    7722    lenovo  2.56179E+17 1.34991E+12 113671593   lenovo pass hp top pc maker Lenovo passes HP to be top PC maker
```

The duplicate of tweet token (column[5]) that still exist in the output is:
`hp lenovo battl top spot pc market computerworld`

How can I remove the existing duplicates?

Comment: What defines a pair of lines as being duplicate, and which line should be retained?

Comment: The rules for parsing CSV are a little tricky, and splitting on commas is not going to work in the presence of quoted text fields containing commas.  You should be using an existing CSV parsing library.  Also you haven't specified what you mean by "duplicate".

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the column[5] that have the same string are duplicate, the line's timestamp that come first should be retained

Comment: @JimGarrison I have edited my question. Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

You can get around this easily with [univocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial). It's also going to parse your data much faster than all that code you've written.

```
// creates a CSV parser
CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings(); // configure parse as required
CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);

Set<String> tweets = new HashSet<>();
for(String[] row : parser.iterate(new File("/path/to/input.csv"))){
    if(tweets.contains(row[5])){
        //duplicate, skip.
        continue;
    } else {
        tweets.add(row[5]);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row)); // process the row
    }
}
```

Hope it helps

Disclosure: I am the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache V2.0 license).

Comment: why do you need to check contains in a Set?

Comment: if the value is in the set it means another row had the same thing at column 5.

Comment: @JeronimoBackes it is able to remove duplicate with the code I wrote in the question, without using `CsvParserSettings`

Comment: @user7146946 your code is not reliable to parse the CSV input. You will have to use a CSV parser. You can't just use `data.split(",");` as you did because the tweet message can contain the `,` character itself. You also may need to handle quotes and line endings inside the message. Your code won't work if you have a message with `42" TV, broken.\nReturned`